# Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'

Tags: android, genymotion

Eu instalei o emulador Genymotion no Android Studio, mas acontece que quando vou executar meu app no emulador ele me retorna o seguinte erro:

> Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'

Ja tentei seguir esse [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32846045/i-am-getting-could-not-open-sys-class-power-supply-genymotion-fake-path-prese) mas nao resolveu meu problema!

Alguem saberia me dizer a causa do problema?

Answer (score 2):

Certamente já deve ter resolvido seu problema, mas como eu também passei por isto, decidi postar como eu solucionei isto.

O meu problema foi resolvido declarando a Activity no AndroidMainfest.
Simples assim... um erro de atenção. :D

```
        <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```